# Evaluating a difficult 3-dimension dirac delta

Tags: functional-analysis, special-functions, dirac-delta

Currently doing problem 1.48 of "Introduction to electrodynamics by David Griffith"
I've read the examples, the theory and understood but come the exercise the author has a terrible habit of dishing out non-related questions!

This is where I am struggling:

$\int \left ( r^{2} +\vec{v}.\vec{a}+a^{2}\right )\delta^{3}\left ( \vec{r}-\vec{a} \right )d\tau$

Tried expanding but couldn't see any way around. Help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the domain of integration? And what is $\tau$?

Comment: tau is infinitesimal volume dV

Comment: i got 3$/vec{a}$ which I'm unsure if it is correct

Comment: Is $v = a$?${}{}{}$

Comment: yes. i got 3a^2 where a is a vector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the very definition of the dirac distribution, we have for any function $f \in C^0(\mathbf R^3)$ that 
$$ \int_{\mathbf R^3} f(x)\delta(x-a)\, dx = f(a) $$
In your case, we have 
$$ f(x) = \def\abs#1{\left|#1\right|}\abs x^2 + \langle x,a\rangle + \abs a^2 $$ Hence,
\begin{align*}
  \int_{\mathbf R^3}\bigl(\abs x^2 + \langle x,a\rangle + \abs a^2\bigr) \delta(x-a)\, dx &= f(a)\\
                 &= \abs a^2 +\langle a,a\rangle + \abs a^2\\ 
                 &= 3\abs a^2
\end{align*}
So, you are correct.
\end{align*}